# How to properly store and extract AZURE_TENANT_ID, AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, azure-keyvault, connected-services

I have this azure key vault in which I have stored an api key.
I have via Visual studio added the azure key vault as an connected service to the project.

I try to get my keyvalue stored in akv via this code

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string keyVaultName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web-kv")) ? Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("web-kv") : throw new ArgumentNullException("web-kv");
    string kvUri = "https://" + keyVaultName + ".vault.azure.net";
    bool success = Uri.TryCreate(kvUri, UriKind.Absolute, out Uri uri);
    if(!success)
    {
        throw new Exception(kvUri);
    }
        var akvClient = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var apiKey = akvClient.GetSecret("LicenseApiKey");
```

Which returns this exception

```
Azure.Identity.AuthenticationFailedException: The DefaultAzureCredential failed to retrieve a token from the included credentials.
  EnvironmentCredential is unavailable Environment variables not fully configured. AZURE_TENANT_ID and AZURE_CLIENT_ID must be set, along with either AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET or AZURE_USERNAME and AZURE_PASSWORD. Currently set variables [  ].
  ManagedIdentityCredential is unavailable No managed identity endpoint found..
  SharedTokenCacheCredential is unavailable No accounts were discovered in the shared token cache. To fix, authenticate through tooling supporting azure developer sign on..
```

the application is not registerd as an APP in azure, and for some reason it does not detect that the environment variable is set?

Comment: I ended up using a similar approach as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71095915/how-to-access-an-azure-keyvault-from-an-non-registeres-app-net-framework-webap

Comment: Where are you hosting your application? If in Azure (ex as an app service) you most likely want to use the ManagedIdentity, as that is the most secure/least maintenance option.

Comment: The application is not hosted in azure its on premise. 
It has been registered as an app in azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an approach where I let the Azure pipeline insert the secrets into my appSetting when  I am deploying, hence the code will not be interfacing with the keyvault.

Answer (score -1):

On development environment you need to use SecretManager as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-6.0#secret-storage-in-the-development-environment).

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=windows) you can find a deep dive with a working sample.

Comment: but I also need a way make use of this on a production environment, storing secrets might work for development only.

Comment: Just follow the second link, the working sample is a step by step tutorial to achive this with both remote (default) and local (optional) configurations.